# Given that $\binom{16}r =\binom{16}{2r + 1}$, what is the value of $r$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Solve
>   $$\displaystyle\binom{16}r =\binom{16}{2r + 1}.$$

From what I understand:

$$\displaystyle\frac{16!}{r!(16-r)!}=\frac{16!}{(2r+1)!(16-(2r+1))!}$$

$$\implies r!(16-r)! = (2r+1)!(16-(2r+1))!$$

But I am stuck at this point.
If there is any straightforward way to solving this problem, please describe it.

Comment: https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Permutations.faq.question.1019557.html

Comment: Use ${n\choose m}={n\choose n-m}$ and $r\ne 2r+1$ to find $r=16-(2r+1)\Rightarrow r=5$.

Comment: Don't forget that any negative integer $r$ is a trivial solution.

Comment: @user10354138, and any integer greater than 16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question! If all you have learnt is the definition of
$\binom nm$ as
$$
\binom nm = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
then this problem seems quite imposing. How is one to check for which values of $r$
the equation
$$
r!(16-r)! = (2r+1)! (16-(2r+1))!
$$
holds?!

However, if you have the correct tool in hand then this problems opens up to your efforts very easily. The basic idea is given by [@farruhota in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3040313/given-that-binom16r-binom162r-1-what-is-the-value-of-r/3040481#comment6268668_3040313) (and also in [@AmbretteOrrisey's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3041532/279515)), but I believe there is one key ingredient still missing, so I will elaborate on that in this answer.

Now, it is easy to see from the definition of $\binom nm$ that $$\binom nm = \binom{n}{n-m}.$$
Indeed, just plug into the formula $(\dagger)$
and check that LHS = RHS.

However, you cannot immediately use this to solve
$$r = 2r+1$$
and thereby get the desired value of $r$. Because, perhaps there also exist some other integers $0 \leq r < l \leq n$ such that $\binom nr = \binom nl$ is true? One still needs to rule out that possibility.

As it happens, it is not too difficult to prove that $\binom nr = \binom nl$ holds if and only if $r = l$ or $r = n - l$. So, here goes: say $0 \leq r < l \leq n$ and
$$
\binom nr = \binom nl.
$$
Then, using the definition we get
$$
\begin{align}
&&\frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!} &= \frac{n!}{l!(n-l)!}\\
\iff&& l!(n-l)! &= r!(n-r)!\\
\iff&& \frac{l!}{r!} &= \frac{(n-r)!}{(n-l)!}\\
\iff&& l(l-1)(l-2) \cdots (r+1) &= (n-r)(n-r-1)(n-r-2) \cdots (n-l+1).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
$$

Now, in the last equation, both the LHS and the RHS are a product of $l-r$ ***consecutive*** integers. When can they be equal to each other? Well, for ***any*** positive integers $a,b,k$, we have
$$
a(a+1)(a+2) \cdots (a+k) = b(b+1)(b+2) \cdots (b+k) \iff a = b. \qquad (\text{Why? Check this!})
$$

And, *et voila!* We can now conclude that $(*)$ holds if and only if
$$
r+1 = n-l+1 \iff r = n-l
$$
as we wanted to show.

---

With this result in hand, it is now easy to solve this problem. I believe you can take it from here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Binomial coefficients are duplicated at the 'mirror-image' argument - by which I mean $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k} .$$ The binomial 'function' of order n, with k considered to be a variable, is exactly symmetrical about the centreline. So in this case we have $$16-r=2r+1$$$$\therefore$$$$3r=15$$$$\therefore$$$$r=5 .$$